# Is it possible to use template metaprogramming to do compile time selection of functionality that class will perform?

Tags: c++, templates

Often I write classes like this:

```
Logger::Logger(bool log_time_, bool log_percentage, bool log_size):log_time(log_time_)... //made up example
       
Logger::Log()
{
    string log_line;
    if (log_time)
        log_line += (get_time());
    if (log_percentage)
        log_line += (get_percentage());
    //...
}
```

And I wonder is there a way to turn my class using template magic into a code that does the "if (something)" part at compile time.

EDIT:
Values of bool variables are known at compile time.

Comment: So are `log_time` and `log_percentage` values known at compile-time?

Comment: edited my answer, sorry i thought it was obvious, my bad

Comment: are you writing C++03 or C++11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Preface

Two solutions will be found in this post, one using C++03 and the other C++11.

It's hard (ie. you'll need to write a lot of code) if you'd like a true compile time *if* that is **guaranteed** not to have any runtime overhead what so ever (no function jumps, etc etc).

It is however possible, though the code will be quite tedious to maintain if you feel like adding another option to it (in C++03). I'd recommend you to check out the below solutions.

---

#### Solution in C++03

Your compiler should be smart enough to optimize away any call to `LogHelper<+NONE>`, though if you are just looking for more readable code and not a superb performance gain this syntax is quite sweet.

```
enum LoggerType {
  NONE    =0,
  DATE    = (1<<0),
  TIME    = (1<<1),
  PERCENT = (1<<2)
};

template<int>     void LogHelper (std::string&);

template<> inline void LogHelper<+NONE>    (std::string&)   {}
template<> inline void LogHelper<+DATE>    (std::string& s) {s += "1970-01-01 ";}
template<> inline void LogHelper<+TIME>    (std::string& s) {s += "12:01:01 ";}
template<> inline void LogHelper<+PERCENT> (std::string& s) {s += "42% ";}

template<int LOG_FLAG = NONE>
struct Logger {
  static void log (std::string const& description) {
    std::string s1;

    LogHelper<DATE    & LOG_FLAG> (s1);
    LogHelper<TIME    & LOG_FLAG> (s1);
    LogHelper<PERCENT & LOG_FLAG> (s1);

    std::cerr.width (25);
    std::cerr << s1 << " >> " << description << std::endl;
  }
};
```

...

```
int
main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
  Logger<DATE|TIME|PERCENT> foo_log;
  Logger<TIME>             time_log;
  Logger<>                   no_log;

  time_log.log ("log objects initialized!");
  foo_log .log ("using foo_log");
  no_log  .log ("about to terminate application");
}
```

**output**

```
                12:01:01  >> log objects initialized!
 1970-01-01 12:01:01 42%  >> using foo_log
                          >> about to terminate application
```

---

#### Solution using Variadic Templates (C++11)

```
enum LoggerType {
  NONE, PERCENT, DATE, TIME
};

template<LoggerType T = NONE, LoggerType ... Next>
std::string LogHelper () {
  return LogHelper<T> () + "; " + LogHelper<Next...> ();
}

template<> std::string LogHelper<NONE>    () {return ""; }
template<> std::string LogHelper<DATE>    () {return "1970-01-01";}
template<> std::string LogHelper<TIME>    () {return "00:01:42";}
template<> std::string LogHelper<PERCENT> () {return "42%";}

template<LoggerType ... Types>
struct Logger {
  static void log (std::string const& description) {
    std::cerr.width (25);
    std::cerr << LogHelper<Types...> ();
    std::cerr << " >> "  <<   description;
    std::cerr << std::endl;
  }
};
```

...

```
int
main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
  Logger<DATE,TIME,PERCENT> foo_log;
  Logger<TIME>             time_log;
  Logger<>                   no_log;

  time_log.log ("log objects initialized!");
  foo_log .log ("using foo_log");
  no_log  .log ("about to terminate application");
}
```

**output**

```
                 00:01:42 >> log objects initialized!
1970-01-01; 00:01:42; 42% >> using foo_log
                          >> about to terminate application
```

Comment: Why is there a + in front of NONE, DATA etc.? I have never seen that before... (and it works, so I am assuming it has some meaning)

Comment: @Samaursa It's to implicitly cast the value of NONE, DATA, etc. to an *integer* instead of being a `enum LoggerType`, a shorter method than writing `static_cast<int> (NONE)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, although some compilers will not like for you it. You will essentially however end up with a set of different classes as you have to provide booleans as the template specifiers (may not be the correct terminology).

I think you maybe better off using a virtual Log method instead? Then create a handful of classes which each define their own Log method. Unless you have some other reason I would suggest using virtual functions over templates for this case.

Comment: correct terminology is template parameters.  I would make the template versions inherit from a virtual LogBase class.  Best of both worlds.

Comment: I suck at object design, but wouldnt that require derived class for each combination of bool parameters I want to use ?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: not really, if it's a template class.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Something like this:

```
template <bool Opt1, bool Opt2> void foo()
{
     Action1<Opt1>();
     Action2<Opt2>();
}

template <bool> void Action1();
template <bool> void Action2();

template <> void Action1<true>()  { /* ... */ }
template <> void Action1<false>() { /* ... */ }
template <> void Action2<true>()  { /* ... */ }
template <> void Action2<false>() { /* ... */ }
```

Invoke this like `foo<true, false>();`.

Comment: `foo()` is member function template?

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: You can structure this any way you like - free function, member function, or nested class template... whatever fits best. Obviously there are some restrictions on what you can specialize; I just presented the general pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to employ templates where it isn't needed? Any self-respecting C++ compiler will do constant folding based on constant expressions: it has to work out the values for these at compile-time anyway. That is, any conditional based on a constant expression won't be there at run-time. The only two drawbacks of this approach are:

1. you are relying on the compiler to be reasonably decent at a rather basic level
2. symbols referenced from the code never executed my still be referenced

With respect to your Boolean flags you still have to make sure that they are recognized as constant expressions, however. Using a template would enforce this.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** for compile time constants you can use `template` programming:

```
template<bool log_time, bool log_perchentage, bool log_size>
struct Logger
{
  static void log()
  {  // log everything
    string log_line;
    log_line+=(get_time());
    log_line+=(get_perchentage());
    log_line+=(get_size());
  }
};

template<>
struct Logger<false, false, false>
{
  static void log()
  {  // nothing to log
  }
};
```

You can also specialize the intermediate versions as `Logger<true, false, false>` and `Logger<false, true, true>` and so on. The other way to avoid several specializations is to separate `time / percentage / size` into different `struct`s and log them separately.

Comment: @MooingDuck, ok I missed `static`, for `static log()` specialization makes sense.

Comment: this still doesnt seem to match the OP's apperent intent, but I'll retract the -1 since this _might_ be an acceptable answer for the OP's actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
struct DummyEnhancer 
{
    void operator()(string& s) const{
    }
};

struct TimerEnhancer
{
    void operator()(string& s) const{
        s += "time";
    }
};

struct PercenterEnhancer
{
    void operator()(string& s) const{
        s += "percent";
    }
};

template <typename Timer , typename Percenter>
struct Logger
{
    void Log()
    {
        string log_line;

        Timer t;
        t( log_line );

        Percenter p;
        p( log_line );
    }
};

int main()
{

    Logger<DummyEnhancer,DummyEnhancer> foo;
    foo.Log();

    Logger< TimerEnhancer , PercenterEnhancer > bar;
    bar.Log();

    return 0;
}
```

`foo.Log()` will be a no op and `bar.log()` will do both the timer and percentage stuff you want